# Query a custom post type by another custom post type value linked to it by an ACF relationship field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api, meta-query

I want to query a Custom post type **Person**, filter those people by their first name and the name of the **City** they are living in.

But I don't know the **ID** of the **City** but only it's name.

The **City** is in my case another custom post type, linked to the **Person** with an ACF relationship field.

I'm using the Wordpress JSON API V2 to search people with filters, I used the **add_meta_query_to_rest_query** hook to filter my custom post type **Person**, if I add a simple filter it works :

```php
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'firstname',
    'value' => 'John',
    'compare' => '='
);
```

But if I want to filter the persons living in **Paris** (which is a meta of the linked Custom post Type), I can't find the right syntax to do it.
I tried to use *city_name* key.

```php
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'city_name',
    'value' => 'Paris',
    'compare' => '='
);
```

Here is the only working way I found for now, with the ID :

```php
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'city',
    'value' => '"10"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ACF stores related post by its ID, so to match your search you need to use them (That's why it works in your last example). You need to get the Paris $post object so you can obtain its ID from it.

Just search your cities by slug (I think is a better approach than searching by tittle because slugs are unique).

```
$post_args = array(
  'name'        => 'paris',
  'post_type'   => 'city',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);

$my_city = get_posts($args);
$my_city_id = $my_city[0]->ID;

$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'city',
    'value' => $my_city_id,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will certainly use this in the future

I found that it was a bit weird to use a **LIKE** operator instead of a **=**. It's because the relationship field stores link between two post with that syntax : 

`a:1:{i:0;s:2:"40";}`

It's not a real link with an integer. I used **post object** link instead of the **relationship** one and now the value stored in database is an integer.

I can now use **=** or **IN** operator, that is a lot faster than the **LIKE** operator